# Problem with Validation Control in formview ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, formview

I'm having some problem with validation control in formview. I could add a validation control inside a formview control it was working fine until I tried to group them using validationgroups. Also if I dont enter a value the program still allow to add it in the database. Could someone help me point out the problem or error in my program? Here's the Insert statement I've made.

```
<InsertItemTemplate>

                Book ID:
                <asp:TextBox ID="bookidTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("bookid") %>' />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequesFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required" ControlToValidate="bookidTextBox" ValidationGroup="InsertBook">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="bookidTextBox" ValidationExpression="^([\S\s]{13,13})$" ErrorMessage="Value must be at least 13 characters long">
                </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                <br />

                Title:
                <asp:TextBox ID="booktitleTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("booktitle") %>' />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required" ControlToValidate="booktitleTextBox" ValidationGroup="InsertBook">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <br />

                Author's lastname:
                <asp:TextBox ID="lastnameTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("lastname") %>' />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required" ControlToValidate="lastnameTextBox" ValidationGroup="InsertBook">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <br />

                Author's firstname:
                <asp:TextBox ID="firstnameTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("firstname") %>' />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required" ControlToValidate="firstnameTextBox" ValidationGroup="InsertBook">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <br />

                Description:
                <asp:TextBox ID="descriptionTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("description") %>' />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required" ControlToValidate="descriptionTextBox" ValidationGroup="InsertBook">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <br />

                Category:
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                    DataSourceID="categoryDataSource" DataTextField="name" 
                    DataValueField="categoryid" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("categoryid", "{0}") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="categoryDataSource" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LibrarySystemConnectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [categoryid], [name] FROM [TblCategory]">
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                <br />

                Date added:
                <asp:TextBox ID="dateaddedTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("dateadded") %>' />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required" ControlToValidate="dateaddedTextBox" ValidationGroup="InsertBook">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <br />

                Status:
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
                    DataSourceID="statusDataSource" DataTextField="statusname" 
                    DataValueField="statusid" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("statusid", "{0}") %>'>
                </asp:DropDownList>

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="statusDataSource" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LibrarySystemConnectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [statusid], [statusname] FROM [BookStatus]">
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                <br />

                Quantity:
                <asp:TextBox ID="quantityTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("quantity") %>' />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* Required" ControlToValidate="quantityTextBox" ValidationGroup="InsertBook">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <br />

                <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" Text="Add" />
                    &nbsp;

                <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" 
                    CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />

            </InsertItemTemplate>
```

Any help would be much appreciated ;)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user: on which button click do you want to validate the controls?

Comment: Do you have the code-behind for `Insert` command?

Comment: @mahesh I would like to validate the control when I click the insert button.

Comment: @KaeL most of my code are inline how do I make it in code behind? I want it to validate and check all of the required field when I click the Insert link button.

Comment: @User : But you didn't add any validation group to the link button?

Comment: I've added the validationgroup = "group1" but its a bit glitchy sometimes it add the record in the database, sometimes not, sometimes it add if i dont put any value. Anyway I'll try building it again from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `ValidationGroup="InsertBook"` as you have set Validation group to your validation.

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert"
                    Text="Add" ValidationGroup="InsertBook" />
```

Comment: I don't know why but its working again ;) Maybe I've pointed it to a wrong validation group. Thanks everyone!

Comment: you have specified validation group to your validator.

Comment: Yeah I've pointed it to a wrong validationgroup instead pointing it to InsertBook I've pointed it to InsertButton :P